# Apache Spark with Java : Launching multiple app requests simultaneously

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

We using spark with java and created Java REST api to call our spark code. Up on calling the REST url my java method will create SparkSession and Context to proceed with calculations. This is working fine for single request but for multiple requests at the same time we are receiving issues related to SparkContexts :Multiple SparkContexts in same Driver JVM

Also tried using : conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

Kindly suggest the how to manage Spark context for simultaneous spark requests. Or any other means of handling this situations?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of open source options are available.
1. [Spark jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) - Provide a RESTful interface for submitting requests to same spark context.
2. [Zeppelin](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin), [Livy](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy)- Notebook interface for submitting Spark request.
They also expose REST endpoints to submit Spark.